# return highest frequency using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe

```
name    country gender  
Ada      US      1
Aby      UK      0
Alan     US      0
Eli      US      1
Eddy     US      1
Bing     NW      0
Bing     US      1
Eli      UK      0
Eli      US      0
Alan     US      1
Ada      UK      0
```

Some names are assigned with different gender and country. E.g. Eli has US and 1 also has UK and 0.

I have used

```
groupby('name')['gender]
groupby('name')['code']
```

After the groupby, I am hoping to return the "gender" and "country" with the highest frequency. For example, if Eli has two US and one UK, then the country should be US. Same rule applies to gender.

For gender I used > 0.5 rule

```
df= df_inv.groupby('name')['gender'].mean()
df = df_inv.reset_index()
df['gender'] = (df['gender']>=0.5).astype(int)
```

Is there easier way to write this code? Also, is there any solution for categorical variable like country?

Comment: What does `gender` represent? Male/Female? Why `> 0.5`? What does that mean?

Comment: This means if the mean of gender > 0.5, it should be 1 that has higher frequency, so I assign the value as 1. If not, it goes to 0

Comment: Ah. Usually, people just count the number of occurrences and then return the argmax. Especially useful if there's more than 2 levels for your categorical variable. (e.g. male/female/other)

Comment: Let me try to rephrase the question: What nationality is a person with a given name most likely to have? And: What gender is a person with a given name most likely to have? If this is correct, then there are two questions which need to be answered separately. However, you can then combine the answers in one table that will tell you both the nationality and the gender for a name. A question you will need to answer though is how to resolve ambiguous results: e.g. what is Alan's gender? 0, 1 or undefined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should group by two properties (name and country/gender), build a table, and choose the column with the maximum value in each row:

```
df.groupby(['name','country']).size().unstack().idxmax(1)
#name
#Aby     UK
#Ada     UK
#Alan    US
#Bing    NW
#Eddy    US
#Eli     US
df.groupby(['name','gender']).size().unstack().idxmax(1)
#name
#Aby     0
#Ada     0
#Alan    0
#Bing    0
#Eddy    1
#Eli     0
```

You can later join the results if you want.

Answer (score 0):

We can do `groupby` with function `mode` by `agg`

```
df = df.groupby('name').agg({'country':lambda x : x.mode()[0],'gender':lambda x : int(x.mean()>0.5)})
Out[154]: 
     country  gender
name                
Aby       UK       0
Ada       UK       0
Alan      US       0
Bing      NW       0
Eddy      US       1
Eli       US       0
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this will do the work... pls check and confirm

```
a=df.groupby('name')['gender'].max().to_frame().reset_index()
b=df.groupby('name')['country'].max().to_frame().reset_index()
df=b
df['gender']=a['gender']
del a,b
```